# How to standardize the output of USQL

Tags: json, azure, u-sql

We have a requirement to standardize the output of USQL. 
The USQL reads the JSON (source file) data and convert it to csv format. 
The problem is that the number of columns we have for each row in csv is not the same because of missing data in the source. Sometimes the result set of USQL have a row in csv with "N" columns, another row is with "N+1" columns (cells). We would like to standardize the output, having the same number columns in csv for all the rows. 
How do we achieve this? We don't have any control over source file data, we would need to do the standardization  while processing.
Has anyone faced similar challenges and found a solution?

Comment: What is the code you're using to do it? Please read this page: [mcve].

Comment: It would be great if your question contains some sample input and output data.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble guys, Same question has been posted in a better way to understand here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477783/how-to-standardize-the-output-of-usql-to-have-data-for-all-the-columns-when-conv

Comment: You could have edited this one instead :-)